# Can an image be created from a new canvas object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to create a new canvas, do some clipping operations on an image, and returning the new image.

But, even without doing anything to the image, I get an error when trying to render the image my method returns.

```
The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
```

Here is my code:

```
   let image = ImageUtils.getImage("path_to_my_image.jpg");

   let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
   canvas.width = texture.width;
   canvas.height = texture.height;

   let g = canvas.getContext("2d");
   g.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

   let newImage = new Image();
   newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

return newImage;
```

I'm able to render the image normally if I don't try to generate it from a new canvas object, so I know that's not the issue. I've searched around quite a bit and haven't seen much on the topic.

Comment: what does `ImageUtils.getImage` do?

Comment: It just calls this:
        let image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = path;

Comment: getting images that way is an asynchronous operation, you cant draw it to a canvas right away